# Will a dll running .net framework 3.5 be able to work in SharePoint Server 2013 web application

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, .net

I have a custom dll where its target framework is `.Net 3.5`, would it work in a SharePoint Server 2013 web application which runs on `.Net 4.5`?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need to recompile your dll targeting .net 4.5

> "... using the Server Object Model ... To test the code samples in
>   this chapter, you need to create a new  Console project in Microsoft
>   Visual Studio 2012. Next, make sure that the Target Framework setting
>   in  the Application configuration tab of the project from is .NET
>   Framework 4.5. Because Microsoft  SharePoint 2013 works on 64-bit
>   machines only, specify x64 for the Platform Target setting in the
>   Build  configuration tab of the project. Lastly, you need to reference
>   some of the SharePoint Server Object  Model assemblies, including
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.dll, which is the main Server Object Model
>   assembly.  You can find it, along with many of the other assemblies,
>   in the SharePoint15_Root\ISAPI folder, as well  as in standard .NET
>   References in Visual Studio."

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/066b9cac-6069-45e3-a632-e910fd65a5a0/sharepoint-2013-c-application-which-is-created-using-server-object-model-api-build-with-35?forum=sharepointdevelopment

Answer (score 0):

Very probably you need to install .NET 3.5 framework too

Comment: is it a better idea to upgrade the target framework of the custom dll to framework 4.5 to ensure everything runs smoothly? i have the source code.

Comment: sometimes there is no need to upgrade it to 4.5 should run smoothly with both installed frameworks